# Detect Unwind Event in Parent without Child Using Delegate

Tags: objective-c, swift

It is standard practice to use a parent delegate in a child view controller when performing segues, but I recently learned about the Law of Demeter from NSHipster and thought it would be ideal for the parent to know that its viewWillAppear was the result of returning from the child view controller. The child wouldn't have to know anything about or need to tell the parent anything.

Is there an elegant way to handle this?

Comment: When you say "child view controller", how did it become a child?  Do you mean a view controller you added via an embed segue (or via `addChildViewControlller:`), or did you do mean a view controller you put on the navigation stack via `UINavigationController pushViewController:`, or  is it a presented view controller (modal)?

Comment: It's a child by a push (or now "Show") segue.

Comment: You can have the "parent" (in your question's terminology) implement [`UINavigationControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/UINavigationControllerDelegate) and handle willShowViewController...

Comment: Thanks, this worked. You should add it as an answer and I will give it an up vote.